# Error correction capability in NAND (1-bit 4-bit 8-bit)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, flash-memory

I'm aware of 1-bit, 4-bit and 8-bit ECC for NAND. While the technical reference manual of the chipset mentions only 4-bit and 8-bit error correction capabilities is it possible to implement 1-bit ECC on the same chipset?

I would like to actually understand if the error correction capability is present in the NAND controller or if it can be implemented using software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess i found an answer to it myself.. Only the ECC type mentioned in the Technical Reference Manual, in this case 4-bit/8-bit can be used. This means that the NAND controller has ECC in built and it can only be configured using its registers. If the controller is not capable on 1-bit ECC then it cannot be used.